# query builder in sql server of visual studio for select from table where id is

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

i have created queries for login page and it has worked!

it would be of great help if someone could guide me with steps to create a query where i want to display all values on text-boxes where id=__

please note that i am not just asking simply, i have tried many methods but do not know how to make the query using query builder FOR THIS PARTICULAR METHOD

Thank you

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) it is unclear what are you want, there are toggleable criteria pane where you choosing columns (in column named column) and writing conditions (in filter column)

Comment: In visual studio, i had taken data sources , selected my table and took "Edit dataset with designer" and took add query, then in query builder, selected the colum-id and pwd,

  `SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Expr1, uid, pwd
FROM            cat_tbl
GROUP BY uid, pwd
HAVING        (uid = @Param1) AND (pwd = @Param2) AND (COUNT(*) = 1)`



**This code, i had used for Login purpose, check username and password!!**

Comment: what values you want to display?

Comment: name,pwd,userid,mail... based on the value entered!!

  that is like i know the statement is `"SELECT * FROM table where id=123"`

But i do not know how to make the query and to call it in ?

Comment: use it like as you check login and password, `SELECT * FROM table where id=@param`

Comment: thank you, Will try and let you know!